# C program segmentation fault when reading string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My background is in c# and i'm trying to learn C now.
For this purpose, I am working on this sample program.
What I want to do is read user inputs for each property of the Member and also assign Policies to each member in a loop. I managed to get this far but while im trying to read the `Policy_Type` I run into a `Segmentation Fault` error. I am struggling to understand why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

enum PolicyType
{
    Car = 1,
    Health = 2,
    Travel = 3,
    Pet = 4
};

// Member structure
struct Member
{
    int Member_ID;
    char Name[20];
    int Policy_Count; 
 
    // Policy structure
    struct Policy
    {
        char Policy_ID[20];
        int Member_ID;
        char Policy_Type[20];
        int Premium;
    } policies[]; // each member could maintain 0 or many policies - nested structure
};

void mainMenu(){
    printf("1. Add new member\n");
    printf("2. Display all members\n");
    printf("3. Search member by name\n");
    printf("4. Calculate total premium\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");

    printf("Enter your choice--- ");
};

struct Member collectNewMemberDetails(){
    struct Member member;

    printf("a. Enter the member details:\n");
    
    printf("b. Member Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", member.Name); // saves the member name in structure

    printf("c. Member ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &member.Member_ID);

    printf("d. How many policies for the member:\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &member.Policy_Count);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < member.Policy_Count; i++)
    {
        char policyId[20];
        char policyType[20];
        int policyPremium;

        printf("a. Enter Policy ID: \n");
        scanf("%s", policyId);

        printf("b. Enter Policy Type: \n");  
        scanf("%s", policyType);
          
        printf("c. Enter Policy Premium: \n");
        scanf("%d", &policyPremium);

        strcpy(member.policies[i].Policy_ID, policyId );
        strcpy(member.policies[i].Policy_Type, policyType );
        member.policies[i].Premium = policyPremium;
        member.policies[i].Member_ID = member.Member_ID;
    }
     
    return member;
} 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    mainMenu();

    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    
    struct Member newMember;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        newMember = collectNewMemberDetails();
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
    }

   
     printf("Member name: %s\n", newMember.Name);
     printf("Member Policy Type: %s\n", newMember.policies[0].Policy_Type);
    return 0;
}
```

during a debug session with dbg, right after I enter the premium, I receive this error:

```
-- omitted for brevity 
c. Enter Policy Premium: 
22

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000002b in ?? ()
```

I am going crazy to figure out why.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `newMember.policies` is uninitialized.

Comment: You don't seem to allocate memory for the variable number of policies?

Comment: Also both `scanf("%s", ...)` and `strcpy()` are unsafe; prefer variants that won't overrun the end of the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a struct member is an array **without** a specified size, it's called a flexible array member. In order to use that member, you must allocate some memory that matches the array size you need. Consequently you need to use pointers to `struct Member` instead of `struct Member` objects.

When you do

```
struct Member member;
```

there is no memory allocated for the array, i.e. accessing `member.policies` is illegal.

Instead use a pointer and dynamic memory allocation to get memory for the array - like:

```
struct Member* member;
size_t array_size = INPUT_THE_NUMBER_OF_POLICIES();
member = malloc(sizeof *member + array_size * sizeof(struct Policy));
                \------------/   \--------------------------------/
                 Memory for         Memory  for the policies-array
                 first three
                 struct members
```

As an alternative you can drop the use of a flexible array and simply use a pointer - like:

```
struct Member
{
    int Member_ID;
    char Name[20];
    int Policy_Count; 
    struct Policy * policies;
};
```

and do like:

```
struct Member collectNewMemberDetails(){
    struct Member member;

    ...

    printf("d. How many policies for the member:\n"); 
    if (scanf("%d", &member.Policy_Count) != 1) exit(1);
    assert(Policy_Count > 0);

    member.policies = malloc(member.Policy_Count * sizeof *member.policies);

    ...
```

Comment: Mate, you're amazing. Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you must specify the number of structs when you define the struct statically. If you don't know how many policies a user has, you must specify the number of policy struct up to what you think is the biggest, or you can adopt a linked-list (in this case, you must allocate whenever you need to use a policy struct).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I got it to work:

```
// Policy structure
struct Policy
{
    char Policy_ID[20]; // the policy id
    int Member_ID; // owner member id of this policy
    char Policy_Type[20]; // array to hold policy type. 
    int Premium; // premium amount
};

// Member structure
struct Member
{
    int Member_ID; // member id
    char Name[20]; // member name
    int Policy_Count; // how many number of policies this member own
 
    struct Policy * policies; // each member could maintain 0 or many policies - nested structure
};
```

rather than having a nested policy, i moved it out.

and built the member like this:

```
struct Member collectNewMemberDetails(){
    struct Member member;
 
    printf("b. Member Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", member.Name); // saves the member name in structure
 
    printf("d. How many policies for the member:\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &member.Policy_Count);
   
    // without doing this gave me error Segmentation Fault. 
    // after googling I found out i need to allocate memory for my array
    member.policies = malloc(member.Policy_Count * sizeof *member.policies);

    for (int i = 0; i < member.Policy_Count; i++)
    {
        // create a new policy
        struct Policy membePolicy;
        membePolicy.Member_ID = member.Member_ID; // attach the member id to this policy

        printf("a. Enter Policy ID: \n");
        scanf("%s", &membePolicy.Policy_ID); // set the policy id

        printf("b. Enter Policy Type: \n");  
        scanf("%s", &membePolicy.Policy_Type); // set the policy type
          
        printf("c. Enter Policy Premium: \n");
        scanf("%d", &membePolicy.Premium); // set the premium of this policy
  
        member.policies[i] = membePolicy; // set the policy to member
    }
     
    return member;
}
```

and then it worked.

```
> .\policy.exe
1. Add new member
2. Display all members
3. Search member by name
4. Calculate total premium
5. Exit
Enter your choice--- 1
a. Enter the member details:
b. Member Name:
romesh
c. Member ID:
111
d. How many policies for the member:
1
a. Enter Policy ID: 
1 
b. Enter Policy Type: 
Car
c. Enter Policy Premium: 
233
Member name: romesh
Member Policy Type: Car
```